# Subdomains are not reachable after installing new website (.htaccess)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

we having problems with our subdomains after installing a new website on our main adress.

our main adres: https://vlinderdreef.be
Our subdomains:

- https://oudercomite.vlinderdreef.be
- https://schoolfeest.vlinderdreef.be
- https://kleuterschool.vlinderdreef.be

Before the new website everything works fine. Now we can only reach the websites on like this:
https://vlinderdreef.be/oudercomite

How i fix this problem?

This is the .htacces code:

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
# De richtlijnen (regels) tussen "BEGIN WordPress" en `END WordPress` worden
# dynamisch gegenereerd en zouden alleen aangepast mogen worden via WordPress filters.
# Elke wijziging aan deze richtlijnen tussen deze markeringen worden overschreven.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [NC,L,NS]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine on

#Fix missing trailing slash character on folders.
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+[^.?/])$ $1/ [R,L]

#Map schoolfeest subdomain to schoolfeest folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:schoolfeest\.vlinderdreef\.be)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/schoolfeest/
RewriteRule ^(.*) schoolfeest/$1 [NC,L,NS]
RewriteRule ^$ schoolfeest[L]


#Map schoolfeest subdomain to kleuterschool folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:kleuterschool\.vlinderdreef\.be)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/kleuterschool/
RewriteRule ^(.*) kleuterschool/$1 [NC,L,NS]
RewriteRule ^$ kleuterschool[L]


#Map oudercomité subdomain to oudercomité folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:oudercomite\.vlinderdreef\.be)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/oudercomite/
#RewriteRule ^(.*) oudercomite/$1 [NC,L,NS]
RewriteRule ^$ oudercomite [L]
```

Comment: What exactly is _"installing a new website on our main adress"_ supposed to mean? Are you talking about adding a new site in a WP MultiSite environment, or what exactly?

Comment: The order of your rule blocks appears to be off, you have the general WP rewrite for "everything that does not exists as a file or folder to index.php" at the top, and your rules to redirect based on the host name only below that - it should be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I have switched the positions of the rewrite rules for the subdomains above the #wordpress partition and now 2 of 3 subdomains are reachable.

Only https://oudercomite.vlinderdreef.be redirects to the main domain (vlinderdreef.be)

I don't have a clue why this happens.

Comment: That redirect does not necessarily have to come from the .htaccess configuration, it could also be that WordPress is redirecting because something about the site configuration is off.